# C# how to prevent duplicated data in the database?

Tags: c#

how am i going prevent "lesson Title" from duplicating in database when user input duplicate data?

```
   SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
   SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    cnn.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from  Lesson";
    cmd.Connection = cnn;

    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    da.Fill(ds, "Lesson");


    DataRow drow = ds.Tables["Lesson"].NewRow();

    drow["TopicID"] = DropDownList1.Text;
    drow["LessonTitle"] = TextBox1.Text;
    drow["LessonDate"] = DateTime.Now;
    ds.Tables["Lesson"].Rows.Add(drow);
    da.Update(ds, "Lesson");
```

Comment: By first selecting and checking if the string already exists, if not, insert if it exist do nothing.

Comment: You can also prevent duplicates by using unique constraint on table column, directly in database. Here's how it goes: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx

Comment: Can you provide some example ? i am new to this, thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to check the duplicate `LessonTitle`.

**Explanantion:** here i have created a function called `checkDuplicateTitle()`.

this function takes AllRows of a LessonTable as DataRowCollection and `LessonTitle` to be verified as inputs.

it will check the `LessonTitle` of each and every row.
if given `LessonTitle` is matched with existing Titles from Table then this function returns true else returns false.

if the returned value is true we will ignore the updating the table with new row as `LessonTitle` is already Existing otherwise we will add it.

Code as below:

```
void UpdateLessonTable()
{
     SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
       SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        cnn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from  Lesson";
        cmd.Connection = cnn;

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        da.Fill(ds, "Lesson");

     if (!checkDuplicateTitle(ds.Tables["Lesson"].Rows, textBox1.Text.ToString()))
        {
        DataRow drow = ds.Tables["Lesson"].NewRow();

        drow["TopicID"] = DropDownList1.Text;
        drow["LessonTitle"] = TextBox1.Text;
        drow["LessonDate"] = DateTime.Now;
        ds.Tables["Lesson"].Rows.Add(drow);
        da.Update(ds, "Lesson");
        }
       else
        {
         //you can display some warning here
         // MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Lesson Title!");
        }
}

//function for checking duplicate LessonTitle

bool checkDuplicateTitle(DataRowCollection rowTitle,String newTitle)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in rowTitle)
            {
               if(row["LessonTitle"].Equals(newTitle))
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: And how do you think the performance of this will be in the future when he has to fetch the whole table from the database? A simple `SELECT COUNT() WHERE LessonTitle = 'MyNewTitle'` would suffice to know if there is a record with that title already without loading it all clientside.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: Thanks for your point. yes it is good to write in that way but i don't want to write one more query for checking the duplicates thats why i have taken existing datasource.and moreover it is just an idea to the OP how to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

That kind of uniqueness should be enforced by the database. Add a unique constraint to your table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_Lesson_Title ON Lesson (Title)
```